Use same example template in several roxygen blocks
Assume that I have two functions f and g and in my roxygen2 documentation I want that the @examples of g extend the examples of f.
If I write them by hand, it would look like this:
#' Adds One to Its Argument
#'
#' @param x Number to which one should be added.
#'
#' @return `x` plus one.
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' x <- 2
#' (y <- f(x))
f <- function(x) {
  x + 1
}

#' Adds Two to Its Argument
#'
#' @param x Number to which two should be added.
#'
#' @return `x` plus two.
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' x <- 2
#' (y <- f(x))
#' g(y)
g <- function(x) {
  x + 2
}

You see that the @examples section of g is the same as the one of f amended by an additional line.
Originally I thought I could simply use @inherit f examples and amend the example but this does not work (as soon as you add a separate @examples tag it ignores the inherited example).
After having read the vignette on re-using docs I thought that the way to go is to write a function generate_example, say, which creates the example scaffold and call it then from within @examples
generate_example <- function() {
  "x <- 2
  (y <- f(x))"
}

#' [...]
#' @examples
#' `r generate_example()`
f <- function(x) {
  x + 1
}

#' [...]
#' @examples
#' `r generate_example()`
#' g(y)
g <- function(x) {
  x + 2
}

But this places a literal `r generate_example()` in my docs (and even if it worked, it would be quite cumbersome to write R code as strings).
What is thus the canonical way of defining an example scaffold / template to be used in several places?

Ahh, one way would be to place the example code n a separate file (example.R say) and then use the @example path/to/example.R tag and amend the example with @examples:
#' Adds One to Its Argument
#'
#' @param x Number to which one should be added.
#'
#' @return `x` plus one.
#' @export
#'
#' @example R/example.R
f <- function(x) {
  x + 1
}

#' Adds Two to Its Argument
#'
#' @param x Number to which two should be added.
#'
#' @return `x` plus two.
#' @export
#'
#' @example R/example.R
#' @examples
#' g(y)
g <- function(x) {
  x + 2
}

